# Set value inside the local storage AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to set values in localStorage. After the function call I am trying to change that value. please check my code

this is my angular js function

```
 localStorage.setItem("popupstatus", true);
    $scope.loadInitialPopUp = function (){
        if (  localStorage.getItem("popupstatus") === true){ //only show if they haven't seen it.
        $scope.openPopup();
    }
    }

    $scope.openPopup = function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            controller: 'popupPeriodCtrl',
            scope: $scope,
            resolve: {
            },
            templateUrl: 'modules/popup-period/popup-period.html'
        });
        localStorage.setItem("popupstatus", false);
    };
```

I am calling above function in my Html page

```
<div ng-init="loadInitialPopUp()"> </div>
```

I need to load this pop up, from the values set in localStorage. How do I do it?

Comment: when popup load first time, i try to save value in the local storage. after the loading popup that value i change. thats my requirement

Comment: i am trying to load popup only one time. unless when page reload, this popup function calling. i need to stop it

Answer (score 1):

The getItem method would return a String and not a boolean value. Try doing

```
if (Boolean(localStorage.getItem("popupstatus"))){
    $scope.openPopup();
}
```

Comment: how i check true or false ?? can u help me

Comment: @gihankumara can you rephrase your question ? what exactly do you want to check ?

Comment: If you know that the value in a certain localStorage is Boolean. Then you need to convert it into a Boolean on the js side by Sending the value from the getItem method to the Boolean contruction (Boolean(value)). The localStorage only returns string values, so if you compare with a string Boolean it is not a good coding practice to do so. Hope you get what I'm trying to say.